# When double-click an Excel sheet, Excel show Starting... for a few seconds then closes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am IT Support,   When my colleague trying to open an excel workbook by double-clicking, The Excel windows will pop-up a few second (1) "Starting..." then close, haven't opened the file or pop-up any warning, I try to repair and reinstall the office 2013 but .....after few days user   also could not open the excel, now user can open by drag and drop into excel .

```
Win10
Excel 2013
```

[image: excel]

[image: demo]

Comment: I don't think you'd have many options here. You can report it as a bug, but of course it won't be a quick solution. If reinstall doesn't help, then you probably need to reinstall the whole OS.

Comment: Have you restarted it?  haha - but really.  This can happen when an Excel instance is hung in the background.  Use cntrl alt delete and kill any Excel instances you see.  If they are there, then some macro or automation is broken leaving a hung instance of Excel.